# Query execution taking long

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am currently using mysql

I have two tables called person and zim_list_id both tables has over 2 million rows

I want to update person table using zim_list_id table

the query I am using is

```
update person p JOIN zim_list_id z on p.person_id = z.person_id
set  p.office_name = z.`Office Name`;
```

I have also created index on zim_list_id table and person table , the query I executed was

```
create index idx_person_office_name on person(`Office_name`);
create index idx_zim_list_id_office_name on zim_list_id(`Office name`);
```

the query execution is taking very long. is there any way to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Do you already have indexes on your joins columns? (person_id) in both tables?

Comment: Please define "very long". Do you have measurements taken before and after you added the indexes? Are there other indexes on the table?

Comment: i removed all the index but it has made no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes on Office Name do nothing at all for this query. All you've done with those indexes is make inserts and updates slower, as now the database has to update the index any time that column changes.

What you really need, if you don't already have them, are indexes on the person_id field in those tables, to make the join more efficient.

You might also consider adding Office_Name as a *second* column on the `zim_list_id` table's index, as this will allow the database to fullfill that part of the query entirely from the index. But I wouldn't do that until I had checked the results after setting the plain person_id indexes first.

Finally, I'm curious how much memory is in that server (especially relative to the total size of the database), how much of it is available in your MySql buffer_pool_size setting, and what other work that server might be doing... there could always be an environmental factor as well.

Comment: "You might also consider adding `Office_Name` as a second column on the `zim_list_id` table"... do you mean "as a second column on the `zim_list_id` table's `person_id` index"?

Comment: Ok i removed all the index but it has made no difference

Comment: Ok it worked. I re created index on person_id on both table..took only 72 seconds to update. I made an error by creating index on office_name. thanks joel